# StretchViewPort is not working properly

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using Virtual Viewport **Size 855*540**

My code is like

In gamePlay Screen

```
 public void show() { 
    gameStage=new GameStage();
   //Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH=855;    Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT=540;
    gameStage.setViewport(new FillViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT));
    hudStage=new HudStage();
    hudStage.setViewport(new StretchViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT));

}

 public void resize(int width, int height) {    
    Gdx.app.log("Gameplay", "in gameplay resize");
    gameStage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
    hudStage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);            
}
```

In HUdStage

```
 public  HudStage(GameStage controller) {
    //virtual size
    int width=855;
    int height=540;

    Drawable imageUpAK=new TextureRegionDrawable(atlas.findRegion("ak_IconEnable"));

    ImageButton topButton= new ImageButton(imageUpAK, imageUpAK);
    topButton.setPosition(0,height*.8f);
    addActor(topButton);

    ImageButton buttonBottom= new ImageButton(imageUpAK, imageUpAK);    
    buttonBottom.setPosition(0,0);
    addActor(buttonBottom); 

    Label resolution=new Label(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()+"x"+Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), style);
    resolution.setAlignment(Align.right);
    resolution.setPosition(0,height*.45f);
    addActor(resolution);
 }
```

The response i get in return is shown in image on different resolution.

**My Question:-** Am i getting desired result?if not what i am doing wrong.If right what should i do to avoid cutting of cutting elements.

I want the position of hud element should be like **My Virtual Scrrensize i.e (*855X580)** in other scrren resolution.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expected result? Yes. Desired result? I don't know what your desired result is. :)

Comment: I want the position of hud element should be like My Virtual Scrrensize i.e (*855X580) in other scrren resolution.No cutting of buttons etc.

Comment: In your resize method, this line should have `true`: `hudStage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);`

Comment: result is same in both cases

Comment: Is your `Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT` equal to 580?

Comment: oh sorry ,I forgot to mention that is same as height and width i.e (855X540)...

Comment: First everything is scaled up or down, to use up as much space as possible. That means, the bigger the window/physical screen (if fullscreen) is, the bigger are the objects. Then the things are stretched, to match the windows aspect ratio. This results in wider objects on wider screens and taller objects on taller screens.

Comment: plz tell what should i do...i m out of ideas/experiments.share anything that can help plz....